# Match multiple fields in a list?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

How do I return documents with matching multiple fields in a list?

Example:

Each document contains info about a university.

One of the fields is a list of students in the following format:

```
"students": [
  {"name":"John", "age":23}, 
  {"name":"Joe", "age":65}, 
  {"name":"John","age":12}
]
```

So, document 1 has its own student list, document 2 has its own student list, etc.

How do I query to return all universities (documents) that have a student called "John" who's at least 21 years of age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define students as a **nested** field in your **mapping** to be able to execute such queries.

```
{
   "mappings": {
      "university": {
          "properties": {
             "students": {
                "type": "nested" 
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your query is quite simple

```
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "students",
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  { "match": { "students.name": "John" }},
                  { "range": {"students.age": {"gte": 21}}}
               ]
            }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

It will return each document when there is any student named John with age at least 21.